# Wget - Cannot send post data

Tags: wget

I'm attempting to send post data through wget using the --post-data parameter, and I'm sure it's right, but it's simply not working.

I'm using --post-data like this:

```
wget --post-data "type=test" http://localhost/test.php
```

With my test.php script, I dump the $_REQUEST var, and it's empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show me 'variables_order' from phpinfo()?

Comment: variables_order: GPCS